# What cause SQL syntax error in creating table in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When creating a table in mysql query I get the error as below.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'String,
last_name String,
email_address String
)' at line 4
```

I could not understand what is causing this error. The query is as below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees
(
id long,
first_name String,
last_name String,
email_address String
);
```

Comment: "String" is not a valid MySQL column type. See [MySQL string data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html).

Comment: idd, you probably want something like varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using *Java* types in your create table statement.  Try using proper MySQL types and it should work:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    email_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

String is not a mysql keyword. you need to use varchar, or char, or text, or longtext... depending on your needs.

Here's how it could look:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
id long,
first_name varchar(32),
last_name varchar(32),
email_address varchar(32)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as i know there is no DataType String in Sql Use varchar

See this for More https://www.journaldev.com/16774/sql-data-types